# Count of substrings within string

Tags: java, string

My program should do the following:

1. User enters a string: University of the Cordilleras
2. User enters the substring: er
3. Program outputs the substring-count: 2 (Univ**er**sity of the Cordill**er**as)

I should not use .str, but create my own method.

Comment: Please clarify the question. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are regular expressions allowed? What are the requirements for the method? And what have you already come up with? What works? What doesn't? Homework?

Comment: I tried to rewrite your question, but what is `.str`?

Comment: @Peter - I *guess*, he just isn't allowed to use methods from the `String` class. And I *guess*, this is something like homework. @Mark - if it the case, please add "homework" to the tag list.

Comment: @Andreas_D: That's what I was guessing too, but I did not want to edit that part without feedback from Mark.

Comment: @dacwe: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach (checking for substring at each possible index) runs in *O(nk)* where *n* is the length of the string and *k* is the length of the substring. This could be implemented with a for-loop, and something like `haystack.substring(i).startsWith(needle)`.

More efficient algorithms exist though. You may want to have a look at the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), or the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). As opposed to the naive approach, both of these algorithms behave well also on input like "look for the substring of 100 'X' in a string of 10000 'X's.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the first occurrence and count until there is none.

```
int count = 0;
while (str.indexOf(subStr)>-1){
    str = str.replaceFirst(subStr, "");
    count++;
}
return count ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A String is a sequence of `char` values (like an array)
2. Loop through this sequence and for every char (except the last in your example):

   1. test, if *this* char is equal to the first char of your pattern and if *the next* char is equal the second char of your pattern (adapt, if you have patterns of a different size)
   2. If the test result is `true`, increment your counter.

This is the basic algorithm. If you have this up and running, think about special cases, like the source String is empty or shorter then the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code....

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class occurrenceOf_Substring {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Enter a string");

    String str=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" Enter a substring");       

    String substring=input.nextLine();

    int l=substring.length();



        int count=0;      
        int index=str.indexOf(substring); // To find first occurrence


        while(index<str.length() && index != -1) 
        {
            index=str.indexOf(substring,index+l);/// to find next occurrences 

            count=count+1;
        }


    System.out.println("substrin count is    "+count);
} }
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also, perhaps an explanation of the answer would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

step 1: convert mainstring to character array

step 2: convert substring to character array

step 3: compare two arrays character by character

step 4: If at least one of the character in the substring array not matches with mainstring character array starts from first character of the substring, but keep moving in the main string

step 5: If all the character of substring gets matched increment the count and start from first position of the substring again that's it.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class SubStringCount {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter you Main string:");
    String mainstring=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the substring");
    String substring=input.nextLine();
    int i=0;int j=0;
    char[] str=mainstring.toCharArray(); // converting main string to character array
    char[] sub=substring.toCharArray(); // converting substring to character array
    int count=0;
    while(i<str.length)
    {
        if(str[i]==sub[j])
        {
                  j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j=0; 
        }
        if(j==sub.length)
        {
            j=0;
            count++;
        }
        i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
int count = (str.length() - str.replace(subStr, "").length()) / subStr.length();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another one-liner might be: use `split("sep", -1)`, then you have the array length (-1).

**Example:**

```java
String input    = "@human@mail@@com@";
String search   = "@";
int occurrences = input.split(search, -1).length - 1;
```

**Explanation:** `split` splits the input string by the given separator (regex). So it returns an array with the substrings between the separator. The second parameter `-1` tells split to not limit the array length by any means. If split is used with the default limit (0) trailing empty strings will be discarded (-> wrong result if the string to search is at the end). So to finally get the number of occurrences of the search string, the array length has to be reduced by 1.

Comment: a detailed explanation must be accompanied. New users will not understand this in a single read. 

split function, divides a string based on the occurrence of a sub string or pattern

example

var str = "human@mail.com";
var array1 = str.split("@");

this returns and array with two elements
["human", "mail.com"]

using function array length =>  array1.length you get the length as 2 (which is the number of elements )
Therefore the answer is array length -1 which equals "1".

In case if string was "human@mail@com"
arraylength would be 3, and our answer will be 3-1 = 2

Comment: Be careful, if the string ends with "er" in this case you get less then you expect.