# Best way of scanning for letter combinations

Tags: java

So let's say I have a 32 character string like this:

```
GCAAAGCTTGGCACACGTCAAGAGTTGACTTT
```

My goal is to count all occurrences of specific substrings, such as 'AA' 'ATT'  'CGG' and so on.  For this purpose, the 3rd through 5th characters above contain 2 occurrences of 'AA'.  There are a total of 8 of these substrings, 6 that are 3 characters in length and 2 that are 2 characters in length, and I would want counts for all eight.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this in Java?  My thoughts follow a couple lines:

1. Scan through character by character, checking and flagging for each substring.  This seems intensive and inefficient.
2. Find some existing function that would do the work (not sure of efficiency of what function it would be, String.contains is a boolean, not a count).
3. Scan through the string multiple times, each sweep checking for a different substring.

The implementation of 3 is trivial, but 1 might give a few extra headaches and won't be very clean code.

Comment: Have you looked into [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)? It's one of the better algorithms for matching multiple patterns, though it's not really all that different from checking against a Pattern/regex with alternation.

Comment: You could first restrict your search to 2 letter matches. Than you go through the list of those matches and check if any of them can be extended to 3 letters, next is 4 letters and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should answer your question.

> The naive approach (checking for substring at each possible index)
>   runs in O(nk) where n is the length of the string and k is the length
>   of the substring. This could be implemented with a for-loop, and
>   something like haystack.substring(i).startsWith(needle).
>
> More efficient algorithms exist though. You may want to have a look at
>   the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm, or the Aho-Corasick algorithm. As
>   opposed to the naive approach, both of these algorithms behave well
>   also on input like "look for the substring of 100 'X' in a string of
>   10000 'X's.

Taken from [stackoverflow.com/questions/4121875/count-of-substrings-within-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121875/count-of-substrings-within-string)

Comment: The naive approach is faster/easier to implement (took about 5 minutes) and the runtime is fairly fast.

Comment: naive approach works great when looking through small strings. But if you are trying to search through say a book of about a 500 or 1000 pages like when searching a word in a pdf, then it starts to become slow.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to essentially code up an NFA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)
and just run your input on the NFA.

Here's my attempt at coding an NFA.  You'd probably want to convert to a DFA first before running it so that you don't have to manage a bunch of branches.  With the branches it's basically as slow as O(nk), whereas if you convert to a DFA it would be O(n)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }

    private static final String input = "TAAATGGAGGTAATAGAGGAGGTGTAT";
    private static final String[] substrings = new String[] { "AA", "AG", "GG", "GAG", "TA" };
    private static final int[] occurrences = new int[substrings.length];

    public Test()
    {
        ArrayList<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();

        //  For each character, read it, create branches for each substring, and pass the current character
        //  to each active branch
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = input.charAt(i);

            //  Make a new branch, one for each substring that we are searching for
            for (int j = 0; j < substrings.length; j++)
                branches.add(new Branch(substrings[j], j, branches));

            //  Pass the current input character to each branch that is still alive
            //  Iterate in reverse order because the nextCharacter method may
            //  cause the branch to be removed from the ArrayList
            for (int j = branches.size()-1; j >= 0; j--)
                branches.get(j).nextCharacter(c);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++)
            System.out.println(substrings[i]+": "+occurrences[i]);
    }

    private static class Branch
    {
        private String searchFor;
        private int position, index;
        private ArrayList<Branch> parent;

        public Branch(String searchFor, int searchForIndex, ArrayList<Branch> parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.searchFor = searchFor;
            this.position = 0;
            this.index = searchForIndex;
        }

        public void nextCharacter(char c)
        {
            //  If the current character matches the ith character of the string we are searching for,
            //  Then this branch will stay alive
            if (c == searchFor.charAt(position))
                position++;
            //  Otherwise the substring didn't match, so this branch dies
            else
                suicide();

            //  Reached the end of the substring, so the substring was found.
            if (position == searchFor.length())
            {
                occurrences[index] += 1;
                suicide();
            }
        }

        private void suicide()
        {
            parent.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

output for this example is
AA: 3
AG: 4
GG: 4
GAG: 3
TA: 4

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find all possible substrings that are longer than 1 character?
In that case one approach is to use HashMaps.

This example outputs:
{AA=3, TT=4, AC=3, CTT=2, CAA=2, GCA=2, CAC=2, AG=3, TTG=2, AAG=2, GT=2, CT=2, TG=2, GA=2, GC=3, CA=4}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "GCAAAGCTTGGCACACGTCAAGAGTTGACTTT";
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = countMatches(str);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static HashMap<String, List<Integer>> findOneLetterMatches(String str) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) list.add(i);
        return extendMatches(str, list, 1);
    }

    private static HashMap<String, List<Integer>> extendMatches(String str, List<Integer> indices, int targetLength) {
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int index: indices) {
            if(index+targetLength <= str.length()) {
                String s = str.substring(index, index + targetLength);
                List<Integer> list = map.get(s);
                if(list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    map.put(s, list);
                }
                list.add(index);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static void addIfListLongerThanOne(HashMap<String, List<Integer>> source,
                                               HashMap<String, List<Integer>> target) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> e: source.entrySet()) {
            String s = e.getKey();
            List<Integer> l = e.getValue();
            if(l.size() > 1) target.put(s, l);
        }
    }

    private static HashMap<String, List<Integer>> extendAllMatches(String str, HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map, int targetLength) {
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(List<Integer> list: map.values()) {
            HashMap<String, List<Integer>> m = extendMatches(str, list, targetLength);
            addIfListLongerThanOne(m, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> countMatches(String str) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> matches = findOneLetterMatches(str);
        for(int targetLength = 2; !matches.isEmpty(); targetLength++) {
            HashMap<String, List<Integer>> m = extendAllMatches(str, matches, targetLength);
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> e: m.entrySet()) {
                String s = e.getKey();
                List<Integer> l = e.getValue();
                result.put(s, l.size());
            }
            matches = m;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there are 8 specific substrings I want to find, but thank you for the example